# classnotfoundexception sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcodbcdriver and mapping_data_source ::init error : file not found

Tags: java

```
//java program  to insert a row into a table using Statement![the output of the program is shown in the image provided by the link given at the bottom

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.sql.*;

class stmtinserts
{

    public static void main(String a[])throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:test");
        String s = "insert into cricket values(10, 'name1', 10000)";
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        int i = st.executeUpdate(s);

        if(i > 0)
            System.out.println("data inserted ");
        else
            System.out.println("data is not inserted");

        st.close();
        con.close();

    }
}
```

[Click this link to view the image](http://myprogram999.blogspot.in/2014/05/blog-post.html)

My operating system is windows 7 ,32 bit system.
java version is 1.8.0_05.

also give me suggestions about error "mapping_data_source ::init error : file not found".
when ever i type java or `javac`, i find this error.

Help from any one is appreciated.thanks in advance.

Comment: please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23360455/1012575, java 1.8 doesn't have sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver class. You should find another driver

Comment: @SachinFederer Next time please include the Exception as text into your question and do not use external image hosters.